# Initialized vs uninitialized global variables, in which part of the RAM are the stored?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, arm

The problem is that When I define the arrays like this :

```cpp
float Data_Set_X[15000];
float Data_Set_Y[15000];
float Data_Set_Z[15000];
```

I get the RAM overflow error which is: `.bss` will not fit in region `RAM` Timer-Blink-Test_CM7 C/C++ Problem

When I initilaze at least one of the arrays or three of them , the error will be disappeared.

```cpp
float Data_Set_X[15000]={0};
float Data_Set_Y[15000];
float Data_Set_Z[15000];
```

My variables are global.

In linker script file it is written that:

```cpp
/* Specify the memory areas */ 

MEMORY
{
    RAM_EXEC (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 256K   
    RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24040000, LENGTH = 256K     
}

/* The startup code goes first into RAM_EXEC */
/* The program code and other data goes into RAM_EXEC */
/* Constant data goes into RAM_EXEC */
/* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
```

And there is a separated part of the RAM for `/* Uninitialized data section */` according to the linker script.

The RAM size is 1MB and around 800KB is accessible for the user. MCU has dual core and I use the M7 Core. this core can access to a 512KB RAM area as it is mentioned in the Linker Script file. the whole size of these three arrays are 180KB

Here is the linker Script file of my Micro Controller

```cpp
    /*
******************************************************************************
**
**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32H7 series
**                256Kbytes RAM_EXEC and 256Kbytes RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
*****************************************************************************
** @attention
**
** Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics.
** All rights reserved.
**
** This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
** the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
** License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
**                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
**
****************************************************************************
*/


/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x24080000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200 ;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400 ; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */ 
MEMORY
{
RAM_EXEC (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 256K    
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x24040000, LENGTH = 256K         
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into RAM_EXEC */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM_EXEC

  /* The program code and other data goes into RAM_EXEC */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >RAM_EXEC

  /* Constant data goes into RAM_EXEC */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM_EXEC

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >RAM_EXEC
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >RAM_EXEC

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >RAM_EXEC
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >RAM_EXEC
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >RAM_EXEC

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> RAM_EXEC

  
  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `float Data_Set_X[15000]={0};` is equivalent to `float Data_Set_X[15000];` when defined in global scope. So something is not right here. Please post [mcve].

Comment: @EugeneSh. older gcc versions were placing zero-initialized variables into the .data section.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Really? Do you know when they stopped to?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Some time ago. Do not remember the version. I meant the explicit initialization to zero like `int x = 0;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I also experienced this.  , with arm-gcc somewhere in the early 4.x range (maybe 4.1?) . `char x[10000] = { 0 };` would increase the size of the binary by 10K . My code base also had to be built with another compiler which would not zero-initialize uninitialized statics, so I ended up having to define a macro `ZERO_INITIALIZED` that expanded to blank on gcc and `= { 0 }` on the other platform!

Comment: The compiler/assembler determine which section something is tagged with.  the linker script simply acts on that, so you have to first understand what the compiler/assembler has done before you choose to do something with it.  (and this is trivial to see with binutils), are you asking what command line to use to see this?

Comment: as far as the error you can temporarily bump up one or more sizes in the linker script so that it passes, then go look at what went where, did it overflow by just a little or by a lot, did a whole chunk of things switch sections or did you just barely go over, etc.  but naturally if you have different allocations for .data and .bss and you move things from one to the other it will change the sizes of both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Then using this linker script the initialized static storage objects will be stored in the `RAM` memory section as the `.data` segment is stored there.

The initial values will be stored in the `RAM_EXEC` memory section. The startup code will have to copy this data from the `RAM_EXEC` to `RAM`.

The problem is that something (probably the debug probe or the bootloader) will have to program the `RAM_EXEC` memory section first

The not initialized static storage objects will be stored in the `RAM` memory section as the `.bss` section is located there. The startup code will have to zero those

The best way is to see what is actually in the memory and where. Generate the `.map` file to see the exact placement (you can increase the size of the RAM to pass the linking. It will not be the valid executable, but you will be able to generate the .map file)